# How to disable Brackets autocomplete functionality on first letter

Tags: adobe-brackets

I'm using Brackets as my IDE now, and I really like it so far. Except for one thing, and that is if I go to a new line it start with suggestions (autocomplete). So when I move to a new line an hit 'enter' it selects the first suggestion. Is there any way to disable this ?

Comment: what language mode are you using?

Comment: `javascript` I'm also using the Vim plugin

Comment: have you tried removing the vim plugin, to see if it's that plugin or if it's bracket's default behavior?

Comment: You're right, it indeed is the `vimderbar` extension.

Comment: Created an issue [here](https://github.com/daveosborne/brackets-vimderbar/issues/41)